# where is block/about-us coming from in bolt _aside.twig

Tags: twig, bolt-cms

I was just reading through content fetching in bolt **[HERE](https://docs.bolt.cm/3.1/templating/content-fetching)** , which gave me a fair idea of how `setcontent` works. Now i came across the following code in _aside.twig template in the default bolt theme:

```
<div class="panel">
            {# The next section attempts to fill the panel in the sidebar with the contents of the
               'about-us'-block, if it exists. First, attempt to fetch the block with slug 'about-us' #}
            {% setcontent block = "block/about-us" %}
            {# check if we have a title. If so, we know we have content to display. Otherwise, we will
               output a default text, telling the user to create the 'blocks' in the backend. #}
            {% if block.title is defined %}

                <h5>{{ block.title }}</h5>
                {{ block.content }}

                {% if link(block.contentlink) or block.editlink() %}
                    <p>
                        {{ link(block.contentlink, __('general.phrase.read-more')) }} /
                        <a href="{{ block.editlink() }}">{{ __('general.phrase.edit') }}</a>
                    </p>
                {% endif %}

            {% else %}

                <h5>{{ __('general.phrase.missing-about-page') }}</h5>

                <p>{{ __('general.phrase.missing-about-page-block') }}</p>

            {% endif %}

        </div>
```

My question is about the below line of code:

```
{% setcontent block = "block/about-us" %}
```

Where is `"block/about-us"` coming from  ??

Answer (score 1):

it refers to a record with the slug `about-us` on the `blocks` ContentType. It's set up as a resource ContentType. You can read more about resource ContentTypes here:
https://docs.bolt.cm/3.1/howto/resource-contenttype